# Run a system command and return the output in python 3 using Popen class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to define a function in python which accepts a system command and return the output.

Expected output :

```
Process Output : Hello
```

My output :

```
Process Output :
```

Code used :

```
def run_process(cmd_args):
    with  subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True) as p:
        (output,err)=p.communicate()
    return output

run_process("echo Hello")
```

Comment: It works just fine for me.  (though it will return a bytes object, not a string).  Are you on a POSIX system like MacOS or on Windows?

Comment: I am on windows ................

Comment: I just tried this on Windows 10 (python 3.7) and got `b'Hello\r\n'` as the return value. Is your issue that you are expecting it to print the value out?

Comment: i want to print the process output :